# Finding the set of accumulation points of the set $K=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} K_n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, solution-verification

> For each $n\in\Bbb N,$ we define $$K_n=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: \left\|(x,y)-\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)\right\|_\infty=\frac1n, xy\ne 0\right\}.$$
> Let $K=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N} K_n.$ Determine the set $K'$ of all the accumulation points of $K$.

I interpreted the set $K_n$ as two neighbouring segments-sides of a square with the center at $\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$ and a diameter $d=\frac{\sqrt 2}n$.

I wanted to prove $K_n$ 'approaches' the origin as $n\to\infty$ by showing every $(x,y)\in K_{n+1}$ is inside the square corresponding to $K_n$:

$\begin{aligned}&d\left((x,y),\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)\right)\\\le & d\left((x,y),\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n+1}\right)\right)+d\left(\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n+1}\right),\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)\right)\\\le&\frac{\sqrt 2}{n+1}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{n(n+1)}=\frac{\sqrt 2}n.\end{aligned}$

Two sides of the $n$-th square, I think,including the points $\left(\frac2n,0\right)$ and $\left(0,\frac2n\right)$ make $K_n'$, that is $$K_n'=K_n\cup\left\{\left(\frac2n,0\right),\left(0,\frac2n\right)\right\}$$ as $B((x_0,y_0),\varepsilon)\cap (K_n\setminus\{(x_0,y_0)\}),\forall (x_0,y_0)\in K_n,\forall\varepsilon>0$.

I now concluded $K'=\{0,0\}\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N} K_n'$.

However, I'm not $100\%$ sure in the formality and accuracy of my solution, so I would kindly like to ask for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show that $(0,0)$ is the $only$ member of $\overline K\setminus K.$

1.The open set $S=\{(x,y): x<0\lor y<0\}$ is disjoint from $K$ so $S\cap\overline K =\emptyset.$

2. Suppose $(0,0)\ne p=(x,y)\not \in S$ and $p\in \overline K.$  Consider  $T_p=\{(u,v): u+v<(x+y)/2\}.$  Then $p\in \overline {\cup  \{K_n: K_n\not\subset T_p\} }$ because $p\not\in \overline T_p.$ But the set $N_p=\{n\in\Bbb N: K_n \not\subset T_p\}$ is finite so $$p\in\overline {\cup  \{K_n: K_n\not\subset T_p\} }=\overline {\cup  \{K_n: n\in N_p\}}=$$ $$=\cup_{n\in N_p}\overline K_n=$$ $$=\cup_{n\in N_p}K_n\subset K.$$

Comment: May I ask how you obtained $\bigcup\limits_{n\in N_p}\overline{K_n}=\bigcup\lim\limits_{n\in N_p} K_n$? I thought $K_n$ isn't closed because points on the axes are excluded.