# Finding $\left(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}S_n\right)', S_n=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid \|(x,y)-(1/n,1/n)\|_2=1/n,xy\ne 0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $S_n=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid \left\|(x,y)-\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)\right\|_2=\frac1n,xy\ne 0\right\}$ and let $S=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} S_n.$ Find the set $S'$ of limit points of $S$.

My answer which I would like to verify:

> I claim $S'=S\cup\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\left\{\left(\frac1n,0\right),\left(0,\frac1n\right)\right\}\cup\{(0,0)\}.$

Let $A_n=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid\left\|(x,y)-\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)\right\|_2=\frac1n\right\}$ and $(x_0,y_0)\in A_n$ arbitrary. I want to show that $$\forall r>0, B((x_0,y_0),r)\cap A_n\setminus\{(x_0,y_0)\}\ne\emptyset.$$

Let $r>0$ be arbitrary. According to the Archimedean axiom, we can find $m_1,m_2\in\Bbb N$ s. t. $\frac1{m_1}<r,\frac1{m_2}<\frac2n$. Let's take $m=\max\{m_1,m_2\}.$ Now, the circle $B_{1m}$ of the radius $\frac1m$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)$ and the circle $A_n$ are intersecting each other at two points $P_1$ and $P_2$. Then $P_1$ and $P_2$ are also in the open ball $B((x_0,y_0,r).$ Since this holds for any $r>0,$ we obtain a sequence of infinitely many different points converging to $(x_0,y_0)$. Therefore, $(x_0,y_0)\in S'.$

Now, let's consider the sequence of the intersection points $(Q_n)_n$ of the line $y=x$ and the circles $(A_n)_n.$ Then, $(Q_n)_n$ is a sequence of infinitely many different points converging to the origin, therefore $(0,0)\in S'$. Now, let's show the rest of the points in $\Bbb R^2$ cannot be limit points of $S$. I'm going to use the following notation:

$E=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid\|(x,y)-(1,1)\|_2>1\}\cap\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x<0\text{ or } x>1\text{ or } y<0\text{ or } y>1\},$

$F_n=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid\left\|(x,y)-\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)\right\|_2<\frac1n,\left\|(x,y)-\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n+1}\right)\right\|_2>\frac1{n+1}\right\},n\in\Bbb N$

$G_n=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid\left\|(x,y)-\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)\right\|_2>\frac1n,\left\|(x,y)-\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n+1}\right)\right\|_2>\frac1{n+1}\right\},n\in\Bbb N$

$H_n=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid \frac1{n+1}<x<\frac1n\right\}\cup\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid \frac1{n+1}<y<\frac1n\right\},n\in\Bbb N$

All of the above sets are open. Hence, $I_n:=F_n\cup G_n\cap H_n$ is open $\forall n\in\Bbb N$

The remaining points are in the set $ J=E\cup\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N} I_n,$ which is open. It follows that $\Bbb R^2\setminus J$ is a closed set containing $S,$ which means $\Bbb R^2\setminus J\supseteq\overline S.$ This was sufficient to prove all the investigated $(x_0,y_0)$'s are the only limit points. Alternatively, since $J$ is open, for each $(x_0,y_0)$ we could've found $r_x>0$ s. t. $B((x_0,y_0),r_x)\subseteq J\subseteq\Bbb R^2\setminus S,$ meaning there is an open neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)\in J$ in which there is no point from $S$.

I also found a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4251100/finding-the-set-of-accumulation-points-of-the-set-k-bigcup-n-in-bbb-n-k-n) with the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty,$ so I would also like to ask if the procedure can be generalized to an arbitrary $p$ norm, $1\le p<\infty.$

Comment: Will add a detailed solution-verification answer shortly : I think that there are errors in the decomposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going step-by-step through your proof, quoting your own lines for convenience. I do apologize if I'm overly picky about certain steps. I'm basically doing this because you tagged solution-verification.

> Let $A_n = \ldots$ and ... $ \neq \emptyset$

I think it makes sense to think of this step first , because what you're basically doing is, for a fixed $n$, seeing what limit points come out of merely considering $S_n$. But then, $S_n$ is just $A_n$ minus the points $(\frac 1n,0)$ and $(0,\frac 1n)$.

> Let $r>0$ be ... $\{m_1,m_2\}$.

I got the thinking behind this, only after I read the next line.

> Now, the ... $P_2$.

This needs justification. You chose $m$ carefully to ensure that there are two intersection points, but you have to prove that the two circles $B_{1m}$ and $A$ intersect at two points : this is not as clear as it could be.

To prove this, you will have to note that two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ with radii $r_1$ and $r_2$, intersect at two points if and only if $d < r_1+r_2$ where $d$ is the distance between the centers of $C_1$ and $C_2$. The proof of this geometric fact can (in my opinion) be ignored, but you should use this fact and justify the quoted statement.

> Since this holds ... $\in S'$.

This part is clear enough to me.

> Now, let's consider ... $(A_n)_n$.

I don't think one needs to justify why there are intersection points, since the line $y=x$ passes through the center of each $A_n$, so of course it intersects $A_n$. The only problem is in the phrase "sequence of intersection points". This is not particularly well-phrased, because the line $y=x$ actually intersects each $A_n$ at two points, so you should, for each $n$, make a choice about which of these intersection points you are placing in a sequence.

To avoid this, you can just compute the intersection points : for each $n$, solve the equation $\|(x-\frac 1n,x-\frac 1n)\|_2 = \frac 1n$ and from the two values of $x$, choose the one that you can prove is closer to zero.

> Then $(Q_n)_n$ ... $(0,0) \in S'$.

Clear to me.

> Now ... notation :

No comments.

> $E = \ldots , H_n = \ldots , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ ... which is open.

The details are clean, although I'm left wondering if there can be a simplification.

> It follows ... containing $S$. *This was sufficient ... only limit points*.

That statement is false. That's because $\mathbb R^2 \setminus J$, as described, actually contains some points you don't want it to contain. For example, take $(x,y) = (1.01,1.01)$. We have $(x,y) \notin E$ because $\|(x,y) - (1,1)\|_2 < 1$. On the other hand, we also have $(x,y) \notin I_n$ for any $n$, because $(x,y) \notin H_n$ for any $n$ as $x,y>1$.

However, we know that $(x,y)$ should not belong to $S'$. This means that even if the set described is closed and contains $S$, some stray points haven't been removed, which means that the details are not sufficient to prove that $\mathbb R^2 \setminus J$ equals $\bar{S}$ ( in fact, it does not, if $J$ is described as given in the attempt).

Your analysis also misses some other points. For example, it misses $(x,y) = (\frac 12, \frac 13)$, because you can show that this point doesn't belong in $J$ : it does not belong in $E$ because it doesn't belong in $\{x<0 \text{ or } x>1 \text{ or } 0>y \text { or } y>1\}$. It doesn't belong in any of the $H_n$, because the $H_n$ demands that $x$ and $y$ should be *strictly* between $\frac 1n$ and $\frac 1{n+1}$ for some $n$, which is not true for either $x = \frac 12$ or $y = \frac 13$ here. Therefore, it doesn't belong in $J$. But, it doesn't belong in $\bar{S}$ either, because you can check that it doesn't lie on any of the $A_n$.

Therefore, $J$ is missing far too many points , and $\mathbb R^2 \setminus J$ is quite a bit larger than $\bar{S}$ even if it's a closed set. Your attempts to design $J$ have to be refined.

> Alternatively ... from $S$.

This is true, but again, the problem is that $J$ isn't the largest open set with this property, which is what it needs to be , if we are to have $\mathbb R^2 \setminus J = \bar{S}$.

That concludes the analysis of your proof.

---

The question is : how can we refine this proof, in spirit of your efforts to detail $J$? We have two options :

- Go the concrete way : maybe we can, with some more concentrated effort, use sets such as $E, F_n$ and so on to *explicitly* describe $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \bar{S}$ and show that it is an open set.
- Focus on $S'$ itself : show that the set, which we claim as $S'$, is in fact a closed set and therefore cannot have limit points outside itself. This would prove that $S'$ is the set of limit points of $S$.

Let us take the latter approach first, to illustrate why it could have potentially been the easier option.

For this, suppose that we have a Cauchy sequence in $S' = S \cup \cup_{n \in \mathbb N}\{(\frac 1n,0) , (0 , \frac 1n)\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$. We want to show, that the limit is in $S'$ Note that $S' = \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n \cup \{(0,0)\}$. We will now use two facts for this purpose :

- The $A_n$ are (sequentially) compact sets : every sequence in $A_n$ has a convergent subsequence.
- If a Cauchy sequence has a subsequence that converges to a point $x$, then the entire sequence converges to that point $x$.

Now, we start with a Cauchy sequence $x_n \in S'$. At least one of these things must happen :

- There are infinitely many $m$ such that $x_m = (0,0)$, or,
- There exists an $N$ such that for infinitely many $m \in \mathbb N$ we have $x_m \in A_n$, or,
- There exists a sequence $N_1,N_2,...$ of increasing positive integers such that for each $N_i$ there is an index $m_{N_i}$ with $x_{m_{N_i}} \in A_{N_i}$ for all $i$. Furthermore, the $m_{N_i}$ can be chosen to be an increasing sequence of integers.

Try to prove this yourself, and let me know if there are any issues. However, in each case, we can get the result we need.

- If , for infinitely many $n$, $x_n = (0,0)$, then taking just this subsequence of indices tells you that $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence which converges to $(0,0)$ (because the constant subsequence must converge to $(0,0)$). Therefore, $x_n$ is Cauchy, hence converges to $(0,0) \in S'$.
- If there is an $N$ such that $x_{m_1},x_{m_2},... \in A_N$, then the subsequence $x_{m_1},x_{m_2},...$ will have a further convergent subsequence which is convergent to a point in $A_N$. But then, this means that $x_n$ itself has a convergent subsequence which converges to a point in $A_N$. Thus, $x_n$ itself converges to a point in $A_N$ which will also be in $S'$.
- If the third condition holds, then we claim that $x_{m_{N_i}}$ converges to $(0,0)$. To prove this, note that for any $y \in A_{N_i}$, by the triangle inequality we have $$
  \|y - (0,0)\|_2 \leq \|y - (\frac 1{N_i} , \frac 1{N_i})\|_2 + \|(\frac 1{N_i} , \frac 1{N_i})  - (0,0)\|_2 = \frac {1+\sqrt 2}{N_i}
  $$
  therefore, in particular $\|x_{m_{N_i}} - (0,0)\|_2 \leq \frac {1+\sqrt 2}{N_i}$. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $i$ large enough so that $\frac {1+\sqrt 2}{N_i} < \epsilon$ (which can be done because $N_i$ is an increasing sequence), and the claim is now clear. But $(0,0) \in S'$.

Therefore, whatever the nature of the Cauchy sequence, it always converges to a point in $S'$. This proves that $S'$ is closed, and we already know that every point in it is a limit point of $S$. Therefore, $S'$ is *equal* to the set of limit points of $S$.

---

I do not think it is cleanly possible to describe $\mathbb R^2 \setminus J$ in a manner where you are convinced that it is an open set. To give you a quick idea why,  see : [image: this diagram]

which shows you just $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5$. You can see how many regions there are! It is going to be a thankless task to divide this into any kind of disjoint open sectors, without missing out some points. It's a complicated setup ,and I would avoid even discussing this approach after seeing this diagram!

---

What about other $p$-norms? Well, the procedure can easily be generalized to arbitrary $1 \leq p< \infty$. Here's a demonstration of what happens when $p=3$, where I show for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ the sets $S_n = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : \|(x,y) - (\frac 1n , \frac 1n)\|_p = \frac 1n\}$.

[image]

You can clearly see: nothing much changes really, the sets just become more roundeed at the edges and more square-like, but they still continue to exhibit the same behaviour.

> Suppose that $S = \cup_{n \in \mathbb N}\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : \|(x,y) - (\frac 1n , \frac 1n)\|_p = \frac 1n, xy \neq 0\}$. Then, the set of limit points of $S$  (under the usual topology) is still given by $S' = S \cup \cup_{n \in \mathbb N}\{(\frac 1n , 0), (0 ,\frac 1n)\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$.

Proof : We will use some well known results here, which will be required to simplify computation.

The results we will use are :

- For any $z,z' \in \mathbb R^2$, we have $\|z+z'\|_{p} \leq \|z\|_p + \|z'\|_p$. This is called the Minkowski inequality. For any real number $t$ we have $\|tz\|_p = |t|\|z\|_p$.
- The set $\{\|z\|_2 = 1\}$ is a compact set.
- Every continuous function on a compact set is bounded.
- If $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $A \in \mathbb R$ is a closed set, then $f^{-1}(A) = \{z : f(z) \in A\}$ is also a closed set in $\mathbb R^2$.

With this, we begin with the following claim : there are constants $C_1,C_2>0$ such that $C_1 \|z\|_2 \leq \|z\|_{p} \leq C\|z\|_2$ for all $z \in \mathbb R^2$. To get this, note that on the compact $\{z : \|z\|_2 = 1\}$, the continuous function $\|z\|_p$ must be bounded, and therefore we conclude that there is are constants $C_1,C_2$ such that $C_1 \leq \|z\|_p \leq C_2$ on this set. But now, let $z'$ be any non-zero element of $\mathbb R^2$. We will get :
$$
\|z'\|_p = \|z'\|_2 \left\|\frac{z}{\|z'\|_2}\right\|_p \leq C_2\|z'\|_2 \\
\|z'\|_p = \|z'\|_2 \left\|\frac{z}{\|z'\|_2}\right\|_p \geq C_1\|z'\|_2
$$
as desired.

Next, let $B_n = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : \|(x,y) - (\frac 1n , \frac 1n)\|_p = \frac 1n\}$. We will first prove that if $S_n = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : \|(x,y) - (\frac 1n , \frac 1n)\|_p = \frac 1n\}$ then $B_n$ is the set of limit points of $S_n$.

For that, let's take $z = (z_1,z_2) \in B_n$. Let us quickly find for what $x,y$ is it true that $z+(x,y) \in S_n$. Indeed, we need $|(z_1 + x ,z_2+ y)|_p = \frac 1n$ with $xy \neq 0$. Thus, we need $|z_1+ x|^p + |z_2+y|^p = \frac 1{n^p}$. This becomes $|z_2+y|^p = -|z_1 + x|^p +\frac 1{n^p}$ and then one possibility for $y$  is  $y = \sqrt[p]{-|z_1 + x|^p + \frac 1{n^p}} - z_2$. Now, if $x$ is a small enough positive number, then you can see that some appropriate $y$ (treated as a function of $x$) ensures that $z+(x,y) \in S_n$, and furthermore, as $x \to 0$, we have $y \to 0$. Therefore, $\|(x,y)\|_2 \to 0$. From here, we can show that one can choose any sequence $x_n \to 0$ and take the corresponding $y_n$ which ensures that $z+(x_n,y_n) \in S_n$. That will be a sequence that converges to $z$ since $\|(x_n,y_n)\|_2 \to 0$.

Thus, every point on $B_n$ is a limit point of $S_n$. Now, we can prove that $B_n$ is closed, because $B_n = h^{-1}(\{\frac 1n\})$ where $h(z) = \|z -(\frac 1n, \frac 1n)\|_p$ is a continuous function and $\{\frac 1n\}$ is a closed set. Thus, $B_n$ is equal to the set of its own limit points, and hence the set of limit points of $S_n$.

Great! Now, we claim that $\{0,0\}$ is a limit point. That's actually really obvious , just do what you did and find where $B_n$ intersects the line $y=x$. We solve for the intersection points $\|(x_n - \frac 1n, x_n - \frac 1n)\|_p = \frac 1n$ which gives$$
2\left|x-\frac 1n\right|^p = \frac 1{n^p} \implies \left|x-\frac 1n\right| = \sqrt[p]{\frac 1{2n^p}}
$$
after which one possible solution is $x_n = \sqrt[p]{\frac 1{2n^p}} + \frac 1{n}$. Clearly, as $n \to \infty$, we have $x_n \to 0$, therefore we get that $(x_n,x_n) \in S$ for all $n$ and $(x_n,x_n) \to (0,0)$ as $n \to \infty$. We have now proven that every point in $S'$ is actually a limit point of $S$. Now, we prove that $S'$ is closed.

Which is where we demonstrate the flexibility of the argument we gave in the case $p=2$. Watch how much the arguments match!

Suppose that we have a Cauchy sequence in $S' = S \cup \cup_{n \in \mathbb N}\{(\frac 1n,0) , (0 , \frac 1n)\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$. We want to show, that the limit is in $S'$. Note that $S' = \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n \cup \{(0,0)\}$. We will now reuse the two facts we used earlier :

- The $B_n$ are (sequentially) compact sets : every sequence in $B_n$ has a convergent subsequence.
- If a Cauchy sequence has a subsequence that converges to a point $x$, then the entire sequence converges to that point $x$.

Now, we start with a Cauchy sequence $x_n \in S'$. At least one of these things must happen :

- There are infinitely many $m$ such that $x_m = (0,0)$, or,
- There exists an $N$ such that for infinitely many $m \in \mathbb N$ we have $x_m \in B_n$, or,
- There exists a sequence $N_1,N_2,...$ of increasing positive integers such that for each $N_i$ there is an index $m_{N_i}$ with $x_{m_{N_i}} \in B_{N_i}$ for all $i$. Furthermore, the $m_{N_i}$ can be chosen to be an increasing sequence of integers.

The proof is literally independent of whether we are talking about $A_n$ or $B_n$ : it just has to do with natural number-type arguments. We have the same discussion all over again:

- If , for infinitely many $n$, $x_n = (0,0)$, then repeat argument for $A_n$.
- If there is an $N$ such that $x_{m_1},x_{m_2},... \in B_N$, then repeat argument for $A_N$.
- If the third condition holds, then we claim that $x_{m_{N_i}}$ converges to $(0,0)$. To prove this, note that for any $y \in B_{N_i}$, by the triangle inequality(which *holds* in our case) we have $$
  \|y - (0,0)\|_p \leq \|y - (\frac 1{N_i} , \frac 1{N_i})\|_p + \|(\frac 1{N_i} , \frac 1{N_i})  - (0,0)\|_p = \frac {1+\sqrt 2}{N_i}
  $$
  therefore, in particular $\|x_{m_{N_i}} - (0,0)\|_p \leq \frac {1+\sqrt 2}{N_i}$ and therefore $\|x_{m_{N_i}} - (0,0)\|_2 \leq \frac {C_1(1+\sqrt 2)}{N_i}$. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $i$ large enough so that $\frac {1+\sqrt 2}{N_i} < \frac{\epsilon}{C_1}$ (which can be done because $N_i$ is an increasing sequence), and the claim is now clear. But $(0,0) \in S'$.

Once again, all bases have been touched, $S'$ is closed , and we have proved that $S'$ equals the set of limit points of $S$. This demonstrates the flexibility of the closure argument that we used. Note that for $p=\infty$ , the same fact is true.

Comment: $\left(\frac12,\frac13\right)$ is in $F_3$ so it is in $J$.

Comment: And $(1.01,1.01)$ is also in $J$ because it's inside the first circle and outside the second, so it's in $F_1$, therefore, also in $I_1$. There is a union.

Comment: I'm going to read your answer in detail when I wake up. (: I'm overwhelmed! I know, Jane doesn't say that often, but thank you!

Comment: @Autumn I'm sorry that I forgot to ask you this : but your $I_n$, I assumed it was $I_n = (F_n \cup G_n) \cap H_n$. I thought about it also being $I_n = (F_n) \cup (G_n \cap H_n)$, but I thought the former was more likely. That's the reason why I think I got confused ,because on reflection it seems that $I_n = F_n \cup (G_n \cap H_n)$ seems to be correct. If so, then it looks like you're correct on that part and I'll edit the answer. Thankfully everything else I've said should be correct, and good night!

Comment: Yes, I meant $I_n=F_n\cup(G_n\cap H_n).$ I thought the parentheses were redundant because of the higher priority of the intersection.

Comment: @Autumn Then I need to look at that part and edit my answer. The rest still stands, but I need to make sure that your description is water-tight.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that
$$S'=S\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{(1/n,0),(0,1/n)\}\cup\{0\}, \tag{1}$$
but I propose a simpler proof. One thing worth noting is that the right-hand side of $(1)$ can be written as $\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, where $A_n$ is the sphere with center $(1/n,1/n)$ and radius $1/n$ (as defined in the question).

I claim that the inclusion "$\supseteq$" is obvious since it should be clear how to come up with approximating sequences for all the proposed limit points.

For the other inclusion, take $x\in S'$. If $\|x\|=0$, then $x=0$ so it is clearly an element in the right-hand side of $(1)$. If $\|x\|>0$ we let $(x_k)\subseteq S$ be a sequence converging to $x$. Then $\|x_k\|>\|x\|/2$ for all $k$ large enough. This implies that there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_k\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{n_0} A_n$ for all $k$ large enough. Since $\bigcup_{n=1}^{n_0} A_n$ is compact it follows that $x\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{n_0} A_n$. This shows that $x$ is an element in the right-hand side of $(1)$.